# What's the meaning of "designs" in the clause below?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, terminology, legalese

> The undersigned agree that this Fee Protection is assignable and transferable to the
>   beneficiaries, **designs,** heirs and assigns upon written notice of all parties, and shall not be amended without the express written consent of the parties.

Source: [Irrevocable Payorder & Fee Protection](http://AGREEMENThttp://exprofessoeng.at.ua/Na_saite/Obraz_doc/IRREVOCABLEPAYORD.pdf)

- What's the meaning of “designs” in the above clause?

I searched its definition in the [law dictionary](http://thelawdictionary.org/design/) and found the following:

> In the law of evidence. Purpose or intention, combined with plan, or
>   implying a plan in the mind.

There isn't much difference between the common term 'design' and the legal term '[design](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/design)'.

Considering this clause is used commonly, I doubt that *design* is incorrect or changed to *designee*.

Comment: Please **include the research** you have already done. Click the ["research" link](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5039) in the post notice for examples. Please note that ELU is not a dictionary lookup service.

Comment: @Andrew Leach I searched many kinds of dictionaries and law dictionaries, but I couldn't find the answer.

Comment: In that case, **you need to show that.** Look at the worked example in the link.

Comment: @AndrewLeach If you ever read the clause I posted, you would have found out this is not a simple question that can be answered easily.

Comment: In that case, **you need to show that.** Look at the worked example in the link.

Comment: @AndrewLeach You want me to post meaningless and unproductive web search history for what? To prove that I'm not a free-rider? My friend uploaded this question on his facebook wall but he didn't get any meaningful help.  I searched online but I couldn't find any related materials, which is why I uploaded this question on this site.

Comment: It's not meaningless or unproductive. It stops others repeating what you have already done.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I have no clue how it can refrain others from repeating what I've attempted, considering that they're gonna find this page on the top if they search google. Anyway, I edited my question.

Comment: What was the definition of the legal term "design" that you found? It would be nice to know and might help people answer your question.

Comment: The clause as you quote it is not used commonly.  Similar clauses (without "designs") are found frequently in legal documents.  Considering that beneficiaries, heirs, and assigns are all designees, I'm not sure why you think that's not the term intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four *legal* terms in the sentence, i.e. beneficiaries, designs, heirs and assigns.

The meanings of *beneficiaries* and *heirs* are clear. And the sentence used ***assign*** to mean ***assginee***. The noun [***assign***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/assign) is listed in the dictionary:

> another term for ***assignee*** (sense 1): *this agreement shall be binding
>   upon the parties and their successors and assigns*.

Sense 1 of [***assignee***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/assignee#assignee__2):

> chiefly Law: A person to whom a right or liability is legally
>   transferred.

Now, I checked Etymology Online Dictionary and [***to design***](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=design) and ***to designate*** have the same etymology as follows:

> 1540s, from Latin ***designare*** "mark out, devise, ***choose, designate,***
>   appoint," from de- "out" (see de-) + signare "to mark," from signum "a
>   mark, sign" (see sign (n.)). ***Originally in English with the meaning
>   now attached to designate***; many modern uses of design are metaphoric
>   extensions.

[***To designate***](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=designate):

> As a verb, from 1791, from designate (adj.)( or else a back-formation
>   from designation. Related: Designated; designating.

The adverb ***designate***:

> 1640s, from Latin designatus, past participle of ***designare*** (see design
>   (v.)).

You can clearly see that the two words, *design* and *designate* came from the same Latin word *designare* that means to ***choose***, ***designate*** or ***appoint***.

The word design seems to mean "people who are chosen/appointed/designated", but it is not listed in the dictionary because its usage outside legal documents is rare. Personally, I found its usage *only* in legal documents, but I might be wrong.

As the noun *assign* was used to mean *assginee*, the word *design* should be interpreted in the same way even though we can't find the words in the dictionary.

As commented above, designs are broadly used in legal documents and it should be understood from its etymology as explained above.

[Oxford Online Dictionary, Online Etymology Dictionary]